# pdfpages clashes with graphicx (LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.)

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I'm relativly new to Latex and might ask a stupid question... but folling thing happend: I had a perfectly working .tex-file and wanted to implement PDF-documents with the pdfpages package.
As I do so my file only gives me error messages saying:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.
```

Heres my M(not)WE:

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,

11pt,

bibliography=totocnumbered,

listof=numbered,

captions=tableheading,

]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Abc

\end{document}
```

---

Can anyone help me?
Thanksalot :)

Answer (score 8):

pdfpages loads also graphicx, but without options. If you want to load graphicx with an option you should either load pdfpages behind graphicx:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

Abc

\end{document}
```

or pass the option like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
Abc

\end{document}
```

Or pass the option through the documentclass

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
```

(but then it can affect more packages).